# FLASK - Alterar vaiável no template

Tags: python, template, flask, jinja2

Passei para o template uma variável e preciso alterar (no template) o valor da mesma. 
Ex.: no controller: `return render_template('index.html', start_code = start_code)`. Preciso alterar `start_code` lá no template. Como faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para alterar/atribuir variáveis dentro do template usa-se:

```
{% set variavel = valor %}
```

Ex:

```
{% set active_page = "index" %}
```

Referências:

- [setting variables](https://overiq.com/flask/0.12/basics-of-jinja-template-language/#setting-variables)
- [doc - tricks](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/tricks/)

Comment: Muito obrigado @Tuxpilgrim, funcionou!
Eu havia lido a documentação no link http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#variables, cheguei ver alguns comentários sobre o comando **{% set %}**, mas não consegui o resultado esperado.
Grande abraço!!